# AutoHotKey Problems

Tags: autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script that has two parts, and it seems one part is causing the other to stop working.

One part is responsible for whenever I edit the script, it reloads it on `c-s`.

Second part, maps `LCtrl` to `Apps` key whenever I use ConEmu.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
If WinActive("script.ahk") {
  $>^s::
    Send >^s
    Sleep, 100
    Reload
  Return
}

#IfWinActive, ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
{
  LCtrl::AppsKey
}
```

If I keep the `LCtrl`->`Apps` remapping, the auto-reloading stops working.

Why?

Comment: The first If doesn't do anything in for the the Hotkey below it. It is a regular If. It should either be #If (you forgot the # in front of it) or you have to use #IfWinActive in both cases.

Comment: I don't understand, your saying using a regular if is useless? I tried using the #if directive, and it yields the same results.

Comment: Is the script actually still running when it "stops working"?  Use `#IfWinActive` as directed and a `#Persistent` statement.  
There are two blocks of code in a script, auto-execute code, starting from the top, and hotkey/hotstring code, defined using hotkey definitions. It looks to me like the regular `If` statement would get executed immediately and then the script would exit, and using an `#IfWinActive` statement would not execute immediately (as desired) and the script would execute (not desired).  `#Persistent` would keep the script in memory and only execute on matching hotkeys.

Comment: Yes, it does not exit, there's no need for persistence.

Comment: As ConEmu has its own keyboard hook it may be that AutoHotkey hotkeys simply won't work - you may be better off remapping the keys you want to use in the Settings of ConEmu itself.

Comment: Actually, I might have not specified this, the problem is with the c-s hotkey, the ConEmu hotkey works fine.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the if statement in front of the c-s hotkey? (and just manually make sure you are in the right program while testing?)  When the script is running you can open the window from the tray and look at the keys received/processed (after opening the window, hitting keys, and pressing F5 to refresh)--do your key presses show up in that window?

Comment: On my end, `Reload` seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you did try the following using #IfWinActive for the script.ahk hotkey?

```
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 

#IfWinActive script.ahk
$>^s::
Send ^s
Sleep, 100
Reload
Return

#IfWinActive, ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
LCtrl::AppsKey
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason seems to be the TitleMatchMode.

Additionally

```
if Winactive("script.ahk")
```

Will run only once, it's not that kind of an if-case
If you want to conditionally enable hotkeys, put them in between #if- statements

Try this:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode,Slow

#IfWinActive, edit.ahk
~$>^s::
    Sleep, 100
    Reload
Return

#IfWinActive, ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
    LCtrl::AppsKey
#If
```